# Save data from Firestore localy

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best way to save data(after fetching it from Firestore) locally?

I don't want to reload it one more time, but only get updates. Now, I have to reload data every time when open fragment with the news. Now all working but it irritates me when reloading appears.

I'm using `onSuccessListener` and `OnCompleteListener`

```
ref.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() { ... }
```

Comment: Firebase is not designed to follow offline first strategy, which is what you're requiring. The solution I could see in your case is you have to use SQLite Database as well, along with Firestore, and design the whole Model layer yourself that serves "Offline First Strategy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android and iOS, [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) is enabled by default. This means that Firestore creates a local copy of your database so it can be queries even if offline. So if you have a database and nothing is changed, then you'll query the cached version of your database. When new data is available, only that data is donwloaded.

Comment: I know about offline capabilities. I want to save data after loading, because next time I open fragment data is downloading again and it takes time

Comment: Agreed, it has offline support, but I doubt if FireStore is at all aware of "Offline First Strategy".

Comment: When you are using a `get()` call, as I see your code, it means that you are getting the data only once. So second time you open the activity you are getting from the cache and not from Firebase servers. But don't use Cloud Firestore as an offline database. It is really designed as an online database that came work for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected. If you only need a offline database then just use Room, as Chintan Soni mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Is there a way to save that data into internal storage instead of keep it in cache. If it stays at cache when user makes some deep cleans and other the cache may get deleted.

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations You can save the data in a local database if you need that.

Comment: Then do that make real-time updates if the data changes in firestore..!!